# JSF - detect when user has exited browser window

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

In my application I have created some locking / unlocking functionality based on the current page that the user is viewing. A user can view a page and will acquire a lock which is stored in my database, when they navigate away the lock is released and the database is updated.

I am trying to handle the situation when the user closes the browser window without logging out. They will still be holding the lock and I need that to be released and a database call needs to occur.

Is there a way to handle this in a JSF application using Spring or something else?

I know the javascript function onbeforeunload but I need to call a java method that will enable me to update the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `unload` and `beforeunload` events aren't going to help you here since it's not by the specification guaranteed that any ajax request which is fired within those events is ever going to successfully hit the server. More than often, this won't.

The most reliable way is to keep the server side session lifetime very short, e.g. 1 minute and introduce an ajax poller on the page which polls within the same session to the server every minute (minus a few seconds) until the user is been inactive for more than the *actual* maximum session timeout. The user activity can be tested by listening on JavaScript keyboard (`keyup`) and mouse (`click`) events.

Comment: but if a user exits a browser window isn't the state of the ajax poller lost since it resides in the current users' session? This might be my lack of knowledge of how everything works so sorry if this is not a correct assumption. @BalusC

Comment: The poller is there to keep the session alive. The short session lifetime will cause that it expires 1 minute after the last poll. When the user closes the page, the poller stops and the session will expire. True, there's a gap period of max 1 minute, but better than that you won't get.

Comment: how about the @PreDestroy, will it be useful in this situation ?

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a two window application and needed to detect when a window is closed.

My JSF application uses ICEfaces.  It provides an `@WindowDisposed` annotation for ViewScoped beans.  With this annotation, the ViewScoped bean's `@PreDestroy` method will be called when the window is closed.

I have included an `h:inputHidden` tag in my page bound to the viewScoped bean and this works in terms of detecting the window closing and executing server side code.